# select("a/text()").extract() does not work

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the text inside of href tag. Basically, I am trying to scrap android bugs at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

```
<td class="vt col_4" width="100%" onclick="if (!cancelBubble) _goIssue(0)">
<a onclick="cancelBubble=true" href="../../android/issues/detail id=58866&amp;colspec=ID Type Status Owner Summary Stars">

compass not showing right direktion

</a>
</td>
```

This is my code:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "craig"

start_urls = ["https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//td[@class='vt col_4']")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraiglistSampleItem()
        item ["id"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["type"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I tested it out on other href and it works fine. Does anyone know why this won't work on the href that shows bug summary above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your iteration variable has the same name as the variable that you're iterating over, which isn't a good idea. Also, you have to select every other row:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    start_urls = ["https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        table = hxs.select("//table[@id='resultstable']")

        for title in table.select("tr/td[@class='vt col_4'][2]"):
            item = CraiglistSampleItem()
            item["id"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
            item["type"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()

            yield item
```